# Articles before family members

Tags: articles

When do we need to put articles before family members for instance sometimes I hear people saying dad and other time a dad. What's the rule?

Answer (score 10):

When used as a proper noun (the *name* that a child uses to address or refer to their father, as in *Hello Dad!, I'm speaking to Dad*) it's [capitalized, and *doesn't* take an article...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20dad%2Cto%20Dad&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

When it just identifies a family relationship (as in *I gave it to a brother, ...a sibling, ...a cousin*) it's [not capitalized and *does* take an article...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+a+dad%2Cto+a+Dad&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

---

TL;DR:
As a name, ***Dad*** is capitalized, and doesn't normally take an article (***The Dad, A Dad, The John, A John*** are all unlikely / invalid).

As a family relationship, ***dad*** is an informal alternative to ***father*** which is *not* capitalized. It can be preceded by an article or pluralized *(John is **a dad** now, The **dads** took their children to the park).*

Comment: I might be good to be explicit that, when just describing a family relationship, words like "dad", "sister", "brother", etc., behave like other improper nouns. (Currently you only mention articles and pluralization.) We can have "a dad", "the dad", "my dad", "your dad", and "most dads"—just like we can have "a cat", 'the cat", "my cat", "your cat", and "most cats". The way that the question was phrased makes me wonder if that was unclear.

Comment: Well, "dad" doesn't *quite* behave like cats or brothers - you can have *my brothers, his cats*, but not *her dads* (ordinarily! :)

Comment: "Her dads" is definitely fine. Even if we aren't referring to the married fathers of a child, I could also imagine the organizer of an outing for fathers saying, "Ok, where are my dads?" to refer to the group—not particularly formal, but also not uncommon.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard also step-parents are frequently referred to simply as "mum" or "dad" without the qualification of "step-"

Comment: I suspect that "to dad" in the first graph is artificially high.  Some may be  due to lazy typing/phone input, but then there are things like *"My kids don't like me **to dad** dance"* ("dad joke" is another rare phrasal verb, more commonly a noun).  *"Dad"* can also rarely and colloquially [be used as a verb](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dad) (Dictionary.com: "to act as a father toward")

Comment: @FumbleFingers the sitcom ["My two Dads"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Two_Dads) dates back to 1987.  The insertion of "two" doesn't change the concept much